# How to pass a WordPress post ID to HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html

I have a WordPress site that lists custom post type items in isotope layout. Every item has a favorite button. Once you favorite it, a star will be highlighted via CSS. When you go to that item, I want to be able to see that this item has been favorited.

I just realized that the script I have doesn't store the ID of that button so it doesn't show it on a singular page, just to the page where it was favorited. Here's the script:

```
  if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
  } else {
      $(".grid-item").each(function(i, el) {
        if (localStorage['fav' + i] == 'addfave') {
          $(this).addClass('addfave');
        }
      });
  }

  $(document).ready( function() {

    // ADD FAVE


    $( ".fav" ).click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var $item = $(this).closest('.grid-item');
      var index = $('.grid-item').index($item);

      //localStorage.removeItem('background');
      $item.toggleClass('addfave');

      if ($item.hasClass('addfave')) {
        console.log(index)
        localStorage.setItem('fav' + index, 'addfave');
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('fav' + index);

        if (localStorage['fav' + i] == null) {
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

My button looks like this and I display the star in the span tag using CSS

```
<a href="#" id="fav<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="fav" title="[+] Add as favorite"><span></span></a>
```

Comment: save your post ids in localStorage and single post/page to match id in localStorage. Modify scripts https://jsfiddle.net/user5200704/tkuqwdvg/

Comment: did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have an post id in your link id so no need to redo that, you simply had to change from identifying grid items using their index number to using the post id.

```
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
  } else {
    console.log(localStorage);

      $(".fav").each(function(i, el) {
        if (localStorage[el.id] == 'addfave') {
          $(this).closest('.grid-item').addClass('addfave');
        }
      });
  }

  $(document).ready( function() {

    // ADD FAVE


    $( ".fav" ).click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var $item = $(this).closest('.grid-item');
      var index = this.id;

      //localStorage.removeItem('background');
      $item.toggleClass('addfave');

      if ($item.hasClass('addfave')) {
        localStorage.setItem( index, 'addfave');
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(index); 
      }
    });
  });
```

To demonstrate have a look at the jsfiddle below, its not very exciting but it will turn red when favorited, you can add in more grid-items and change the order, it will favorite the correct item.

https://jsfiddle.net/a71b4zd8/6/

Now i dont know where you mean by singular page, but im assuming on a single page template. The function above will not be suitable for marking a favorite on that page. I don't know your html structure, but a typical id used to uniquely identify the page might be `post-{$postif}`

You should allow for this when creating the script to check the post ids off against each other.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried the script and it worked in favoriting the grid wih the ID. I still need to compare the local storage to the post ID on a single page though.

Comment: that will be easy enough, ask a new question with your html and reply with the link

Answer (score 0):

This calls for some [script localization](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Where you enqueue your scripts you can do something like:

```
global $post;
wp_localize_script( 'main-js', 'my_object', array( 'post_id' => $post->ID ) );
```

`main-js` should be the name of the script before which you want the localized script content to be output.

Then in your javascript file you can access this object and its `post_id` property and do what you want with the value like so:

```
var post_id = my_object.post_id;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm new to this script localization thing. That main-js is a file right? I'm using FoundationPress so I have all my scripts on a folder in assets/javascript/custom/myscript.js. So shoud I put main-js.js to the same directory? how will the script localization find that file?

Comment: main-js is the name that's assigned to the script when it's enqueued the way Wordpress would like you to (just an example, you might name it something else.) If you're not enqueuing your custom script I might recommend you do so so that you can then localize scripts and so forth. Let me look into FoundationPress as I'm not familiar with it and I'll edit my answer with some further clarification.

Comment: Actually, it is enqueued on  enqueue-scripts.php. The name of the file is foundation.js so 'foundation' is the name that I replace with your main-js. But I have a custom.js that npm rebuilds on foundation.js. custom.js is where I have all my custom scripts but it all minified under foundation.js. 

Now I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: my_object is not defined`

Comment: Hey wait, I think I got it. I put the wp_local_script after the enqueque script and the error is gone. Let me try to incorporate this id in the fave button and I'll get back here.

Comment: Ah okay. Was in the process of editing my answer but it seems you've got it. A quick view source of the bottom of your page will confirm that the script tag with `my_object` is being output before foundation.js

Comment: I think I have a bigger problem. I can see that your script shows the ID of page, but not the IDs of each custom post type. You see I have a page template that houses all custom post types so I it can be displayed thru an isotope layout. Is there a way it can get those custom post type IDs instead of the page template?

Comment: I wonder if I can just add a data-id to the button. I think this is a much easier step.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your problem might be simpler than I was thinking, and the content of my answer is probably of no use in this case. You're outputting the custom post type id to the id of the button in the loop, so why not just grab that or as you mentioned add a `data-id` attribute? Could you post a little bit more of your markup? as I don't quite have a full picture of what's going on.